# Splitting Elements in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array consisting of a color shading (lightgreen, red, blue, etc.) as well as having a number in regards to the colors "strength" (1000, 1200, 400, etc.)

The lines are read in through a `.txt` file as follows

> light green 1200
>
> red 1000
>
> blue 400

I was wondering if there is a way to split the two elements into distinct arrays (one for String and one for int) so that I can sort the array by the strengths into ascending order.

Comment: I have tried importing the java.util.Arrays element and sorting using Arrays.sort(object);  I would like to learn how to split it into the two elements but am unsure whether to make two arrays or how to hold the separate elements

Comment: Do you want the array of strings to be sorted as well in accordance with their strengths?

Comment: I want the array to be sorted in order of Strengths with the color strings just following there respective strengths

Comment: The line in text file should separate with a deliminator like `,`.
e.g `light green, 1200`. So that it can be split from Java code easily.

Comment: You can keep the splitted values in a `TreeMap<String, Integer>`, it will be automatically sorted by the `key` value (`String` here)

Comment: @user2948723, You will receive more specific help if you post your current code instead of just describing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem in following steps.

1. Read the txt file line by line.
2. Split the every line into color and strength.
3. Store the strength as key and color as value into `TreeMap`.

**Note:** `TreeMap` will sort your data in ascending order according to key. If you have duplicate stength but unique color than Store the color as key and strength as value into HashMap and sort the `HashMap` according to value.

Comment: I have read the txt file in line by line but how do I go about the splitting of the lines?  Would a toString be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can easily do that by `line.split(" +")`. It will split the line into one or more space.

Comment: @Masud, that will break if he has spaces inside his color names. You have to split on the *last* space.

Comment: @merlin2011, Right, I did not notice the space into color.

Comment: This worked perfectly! The color names are mushed together so there is no spacing except between the color and the strength number

Comment: It would work if there is no space in color names. Rather, why is there space,even, in a single color name ?

Comment: `strength` should not be stored as `Key` to avoid duplication of K in `Map`

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk :

```
cat file | awk '{print $1}' > file1
```

and

```
cat file | awk '{print $2}' > file2
```

so file 1 will have the list of colors and file 2 will have the list of strengths.

Now you can push the int values to do whatever you like.

**Alternative** : You can follow the regex route:

```
str = "Red 1000";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+(?=\\d)");
```

this will only split it before the number i.e. "strength":

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/cF6qD6

Comment: +1 for the regex for splitting. Splitting was the actual challenge in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the color string value and different array and their numeric value in different array(int), them use the **split** to splt the string value u read from txt file then add the add in created arrays

Lets consider if you have **arr as array** has values from txt file,  now we want to get the string value in **color array** and their numeric value in **val array**,  i think below code will help u out.

```
String []arr = {"col 1 200","col 2 10","col 3 500"};

String []color = new String[arr.length];
int []val = new int[arr.length];

String []temp;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    temp = arr[i].trim().split(" ");

    for (int j = 0; j < temp.length -1; j++) {
        if(color[i]==null)
            color[i]="";
        color[i] += temp[j]+" ";
    }

    color[i] =color[i].trim();      
    val[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[temp.length-1]);
}
```

it will not add **col 1, col 2 and col 3** in color array and **value 200, 10, 500 in val array(int)**

--OUTPUT--

if you print

```
color -- ["col 1", "col 2", "col 3"]
val -- [200, 10, 500]
```

Comment: hold a minute if you have space between color name thn wait I have to modify the code.